# Shap force plot not displaying figure: shap.plots._force.AdditiveForceVisualizer

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, shap

I am going through https://towardsdatascience.com/explain-your-model-with-the-shap-values-bc36aac4de3d trying to get the `force_plot` to print.

I'm running Python 3.8.5 on Ubuntu 20.04

I run this code:

```
shap.initjs()

# Write in a function

random_picks = np.arange(1,330,50) # Every 50 rows
S = X_test.iloc[random_picks]
def shap_plot(j):
    explainerModel = shap.TreeExplainer(xg_clf)
    shap_values_Model = explainerModel.shap_values(S)
    p = shap.force_plot(explainerModel.expected_value, shap_values_Model[j], S.iloc[[j]])
    return(p)
z = shap_plot(3)
```

and I get `<shap.plots._force.AdditiveForceVisualizer object at 0x7f1568cac070>`

to return.

I'm not a python expert, so I've tried looking at this data:

```
display(z)
```

whieh isn't defined.

and `print(z)` which just returns the name of the object, and doesn't help me to see what was plotted.

I've also tried using `matplotlib` which is already loaded,

```
def shap_plot(j):
    explainerModel = shap.TreeExplainer(xg_clf)
    shap_values_Model = explainerModel.shap_values(S)
    p = shap.force_plot(explainerModel.expected_value, shap_values_Model[j], S.iloc[[j]])
    plt.savefig('tmp.svg')
    plt.close()
    return(p)
shap_plot(3)
```

but this just gives an empty image.

If there is an error, I don't see it.

How can I get this `shap.force_plot` to show the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is in the manual:

```
help(shap.force_plot)
```

which shows

```
matplotlib : bool
        Whether to use the default Javascript output, or the (less developed) matplotlib output. Using matplotlib can be helpful in scenarios where rendering Javascript/HTML is inconvenient.
```

Indeed, running a notebook is very inconvenient for my purposes.

so in order to save an image:

```
def shap_plot(j):
    explainerModel = shap.TreeExplainer(xg_clf)
    shap_values_Model = explainerModel.shap_values(S)
    p = shap.force_plot(explainerModel.expected_value, shap_values_Model[j], S.iloc[[j]], matplotlib = True, show = False)
    plt.savefig('tmp.svg')
    plt.close()
    return(p)
```

Comment: On their website it has a tutorial for multiple samples (https://github.com/slundberg/shap -> shap.plots.force(shap_values)). But when you try the matplotlib = True, it says that it's not possible  with multiple samples. Any ideas why?

Comment: @NoobProgrammer I have no idea.  Shap is finicky

Comment: It's because it makes interactive plot, and it has to be htm format :)

Comment: And due to the fact that by design you want to show the 'force' of variables of one observation of the model. Adding more observation would make the plot less intuitive. Anyway, one should also consider what is a good `j`-value. Personally, I prefer the best and worst prediction since there one can show why the model succeds/fails.

Comment: The documentation of SHAP is really bad.